# TreeView Control

Tags: c#, collections, treeview

I am developing an application using C#. I am using RadioButtonlist control inside a TreeView. I am getting collection of items from database. Based on the collection items I need to select the Radiobuttonlist items.

For example from the database i got the Collection in this way: Read(R) Write(W)

based on this colletion i need to set up the user permissions.

Comment: I'm still not following... user permissions for what?  What is the collection of items?

Comment: I'm guessing you want the tree to show the permissions (read and write) for users and then be able to edit them in the control. Am I correct? If so you are asking someone to write your application for you. If you post some code showing what you have tried, describe what is wrong and ask a specific question you may get someone to help you.

Comment: And you should specify the platform too. C# is a little vague. ASP.NET WebForms? MVC? WPF? Silverlight? WinForms? (I am sure we could find other possibilities)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your question right you want to bind that radiobutton list based on the items in the database based on the current row item on the grid.  If thats the case here is your solution.

Lets say you have a Grid called myGrid, a RadioButtonList called myRadio and a HiddenField called myHidden (this is where you bind the value you have on "R" and "W")

All you have to do is when a RowDataBound Event Occurs then you have to assign the value to myRadio

for Example, you have a RadioButtonList like such

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="myRadio" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="R">Read</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="W">Write</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

So your code behind should look like this

```
protected void myGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        RadioButtonList rdoAnswer = (RadioButtonList)e.Row.FindControl("myRadio");
        HiddenField hdnValue = (HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("myHidden");

        rdoAnswer.SelectedValue = hdnValue.Value;
    }
}
```